# Checking input elements on Firefox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm developing an extension, which listens to click events on elements.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is there a convenient way to detect whether an element is an input element? Like `input`, `textarea` in HTML, and `textbox` in XUL.
2. If the user clicked on an input element, how to get the position where the user clicked?
   For example, there's an `<input>` element, with its value set to `blah`, and the user clicked between 'l' and 'a', how can I get the index(in this case it's 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every event has some data that gets passed with it in the event param.  You can do something like this to figure out what was clicked on:

```
function clickFun(event){
    if (event.target.nodeName == "INPUT") {
        var type = event.target.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase();
        if (type == 'text') {
            console.log('text input');
        } else if (type == 'checkbox') {
            console.log('checkbox');
        }
    } else if (event.target.nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {
        console.log('text area');
    }
}
thing.onclick = clickFun;
```

You can do this with jQuery which gives you some easy functions to check out information about elements.  Up to you if you want to try out a javascript framework.

```
$(':input').click(function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':text')) {
        console.log('text input');
    } else if ($this.is(':checkbox')) {
        console.log('checkbox');
    } else if ($this.is(':textarea')) {
        console.log('textarea');
    }
});
```

To get the position of the cursor when they click in a text box or area try checking out this article:

http://www.dedestruct.com/2008/03/22/howto-cross-browser-cursor-position-in-textareas/

Answer (score 0):

For #1: it's convenient to use the jQuery ":input" selector like this:

```
if ($(node).is(":input"))
    alert("It's an input element!");
```

But generally, I don't think there is an easy way to tell XUL elements. Enumerating node names would be the simplest solution I could think of.